# Custom font not appearing in the list of fonts available for the target

Tags: ios, swift, fonts, storyboard

I have added my font file FuturaPTBold.otf in the bundle. I have also checked the file in Copy bundle resources. Also , added FuturaPTBold in info.plist.
I am unable to find my custom font in the list while it is there in the storyboard.
Screenshots attached:

[image: screenshot for .plist file]

[image: font file added to the bundle]

[image: Screenshot for Copy Bundle Resources]

[image: Custom font list]

Comment: I only see 1 out of the 3 fonts as part of your target in the 3rd screenshot

Comment: the one that is visible is also not working

Comment: Can you share the font file via git or some other way ? Sometimes the font name and font file name can be different.

Answer (score 1):

This happens to me sometimes. I have a few solutions to fix this:

1. Close your Storyboard tab and then open it again.
2. Clean your build folder. *This can be done by pressing `⌘ + shift + K` (command + shift + K)*
3. Close and completely quit Xcode, then open your project back up again

Comment: I have done all this, uninstalled XCode, nothing works... What the heck

Comment: Try to instal the fonts onto your laptop - first start by completely quitting Xcode. Then add your fonts in the MacOS Font Book (https://support.apple.com/en-au/guide/font-book/fntbk1000/mac). After this, try to see if Xcode now recognises the font; you may have to restart your laptop if you don't see it there immediately.